# Hover two elements without shifting effect

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

How can I hover the div with text 'Myriam lefebvre', and the span 'Développeure-front-end' at the same time, without the shifting effect?

```css
.logo__name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.logo__name:hover {
  background-color: #e54b4b;
}

.logo__name:hover h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.logo__name:hover h1 span {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.logo__name h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', Cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo__name h1 div {
  height: 33px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo__name h1 span {
  font-family: 'Pt Serif', Serif;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700|Sacramento|Pathway+Gothic+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Myriam Lefebvre</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo__name">
 <h1><div>Myriam lefebvre</div><br /><span>Développeure-front-end</span></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the example the code has been shortened, my code is more complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it with the transition statements only on the '.logo__name' , '.logo__name h1 div' , '.logo__name h1 span' tags. Shouldn't be necessary on the hover tags, since it's already implied by the non-hover version. This what you're lookin' for?

```css
.logo__name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.logo__name:hover {
  background-color: #e54b4b;
}

.logo__name:hover h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.logo__name:hover h1 span {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.logo__name h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', Cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo__name h1 div {
  height: 33px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.logo__name h1 span {
  font-family: 'Pt Serif', Serif;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700|Sacramento|Pathway+Gothic+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Myriam Lefebvre</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo__name">
 <h1><div>Myriam lefebvre</div><br /><span>Développeure-front-end</span></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```